# (WPF/MVVM) What's the different between an IService and ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, service, interface

I wanted to use **SaveFileDialog** in my **ViewModel**, But since it's not correct that bind to a View from **ViewModel**, I searched for ways to do that. But I found a few answers that doesn't completely separate **View** form **ViewModel**, Like this:

```
public interface IOService
{
    void IMessageBox(string Message);
    string ISaveFileDialog(string DefaultPath);
}
public class IDialog : IOService
{
    public void IMessageBox(string Message)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Message);
    }

    public string ISaveFileDialog(string DefaultPath)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog dg = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = DefaultPath,
            Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf) | *.pdf"
        };
        dg.ShowDialog();
        if (dg.FileName == null)
            dg.FileName = string.Empty;
        return dg.FileName;
    }
}
```

They said that, this is a **Service** and using it will separate **View** from **ViewModel**. But we have make an **Instance** from this in **ViewModel**:

```
IDialog iDialog = new IDialog();
```

So I wanna know, What's the diffrence between this method and calling **MessageBox** or **SaveFileDialog** from **ViewModel** directly?

***Note:*** Also I find something that said I could use a Service like the above, But implement it like this:

```
public class ExportViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    IOService _IOService;
    public ExportViewModel(IOService ioservice)
    {
        _IOService = ioservice;
        .
        .
    }
}
```

*But I don't know how send **IOService** as a parameter to **ExportViewModel** (Because we can't create **Instances** from an **Interface**!)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't pop up dialogs directly from your VM for automated testability.

If you call MessageBox.Show(), your test will get stuck until a person closes the dialog.

If, instead, you use "IMessageBox", for unit tests, you can inject an implementation that doesn't actually show the dialog, but rather returns a specific value (the result).

Comment: So it's just matter of testing, not separate V from VM. So because I don't use unit testing, I could just use MessageBox.Show() and don't violate MVVM?

Comment: @Mostafa Unit testing is one case. The other case is, today you want to use a MessageBox, tomorrow you might want to use MyCoolDialog, so you can just swap out the implementation class instead of massive search & replace. If you are using MVVM, you should already be using DI, so whats the biggie? Just define a simple interface and stick the MessageBox in the implementation. That'll stub you out for the future.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't know how an Interface could do that! The second part of my question was exactly this. The Interface just contains some initialize methods, Not the implementation. So in each class that uses this Interface i have to define the body of the methods, And that's not helpful at all. I can just write a class (Like IDialog in above) and use that one with already methods!

Comment: @Mostafa, you would have an IDialogService or whatever with a "ShowMessageBox(...)" method or whatever you want to call it. The current implementation would call MessageBox.Show, but you could easily change the implementation out to MyCoolDialog in the future. I've done this with MessageBox and FileDialog and it saved me a lot of time when I changed implementations to something better.

Comment: Ok, I read another article and now I know what you mean. But that's just going around instead of going straight way! At least I know that I don't need such a thing for my current application.

Comment: @Mostafa, I gave you a use case that helped me... the main reasons to write services are for unit testing and easy swap out in the future. If you don't care about unit tests or maintenance, then I guess you don't need a service :).

Answer (score 0):

It's an abstraction used to separate UI concerns from the view model, and to allow you a means to intercept these calls within unit tests.  Intercepting these calls allows you to both prevent showing a dialog during a test (which will block execution of your tests, not good) and verify the view model is acting as expected.

There is nothing special about calling it a "Service" or calling the abstraction "IService".  It's just an allusion to a common pattern

- I need to do something
- I can't do it myself
- I'll find a service I can hire to do it
- I found a service that can do this for me
- This service will do it for me

You could just as well call it "IDontTouchUIStuffInMuhViewModel", but that's not as elegant.

Your second problem is solved trivially at runtime by providing an *implementation of the interface* to your view model.  Your view model shouldn't care how it's implemented ([polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))), so you can pass in a legit implementation at runtime and a fake one during testing.

You can also accomplish this by using [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) or [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).  By using a library such as [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) to instantiate your view models, all dependencies are automatically provided, based on how you configured the container.

Comment: So all of this services or interfaces are just used for unit testing? So with this said We could, as I said before, call the MessageBox.Show() within the VM!

Comment: @Mostafa No... your VM should not do ANYTHING with dialogs, controls, or any other UI element. If it does, you've violated MVVM principles. The entire point of what Will is saying is that you don't want the VM to actually have a dependency on a UI object. Passing an interface into the ctor is a tool to allow you to separate those. Think of it this way: if I were to re-do the UI to show my own custom file selector on the bottom the screen instead of a file save dialog, can I do it? If you do it correctly, the new UI would just wire up to the interface and magically work!

Comment: @Lynn I was reading about DI and IoC just now, And all that understand is that, this question depends on them, And I don't understand how they working! Although I read from a lot of references, But still don't get it! I wrote my application with MVVM and now I'm in the final stages, But I didn't use any DI or IoC in all the program, Or at least I think I didn't! So I don't actually know how I can do something like the one that you just said.

Comment: @Mostafa Stop in at the [WPF chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf). There's a lot of people there that do WPF and MVVM all day long.

Comment: @Mostafa it's really up to you to decide how your code should be written.  There are very good reasons to abstract UI code from your view models.  But if your application is small, and the code isn't being exercised by unit tests, then you won't get arrested for calling MessageBox.Show() in your view model.  Above all else, understand that these patterns exist to serve us, we do not exist to serve them.  Adhere to them where they save you work and pain, and bend them when they don't.

Comment: @Mostafa Somewhere in your code you create the instance of your view model that needs your dialog service.  At that point, create an instance of your implementation of your dialog service and give it to your new view model instance.  `this.DataContext = new ViewModel(new DialogService());` It can be as easy as that.

Comment: @Will That's exactly what I've done! But didn't know if its alright with MVVM or not, And because of that I asked this question. I read an article just know and almost got what DI and IoC are and what they do. But for my current project, I think I don't need such a think and they just got my code complex. Actually I still don't know where I could use this patterns, Because in all the situation we could do just like you said in your last comment!